# margin between td html5 on sharepoint

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I'm trying to apply margin-left between `td` table:

```html
<table class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0" style="width: 280px; height: 280px; background-color: #ee333b;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 100%;">​​​​​​​<br/><img class="ms-rtePosition-4" alt="illustration-68.png" src="/sites/portail-collaboratif/PublishingImages/Pages/Accueil/illustration-68.png" style="margin: 20px 75px;"/>​​<br/>​​​<br/><span style="color: white; font-family: dinpro; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 300;">&#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;Sourcing </span></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default" style="width: 100%;">
            <h4>​​​​​<br/></h4>​​<img class="ms-rtePosition-4" alt="illustration-68.png" src="/sites/portail-collaboratif/PublishingImages/Pages/Accueil/illustration-68.png" style="margin: 20px 75px;"/><br/>​​<br/><span style="color: white; font-family: dinpro; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 300;">&#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;Sourcing​ </span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>​​
```

How to add some space between `td`?

Comment: Why don't you use `cellspacing`?

Comment: how ? when to add it ?

Comment: `td+td { margin-left: 10px; }` this will work

Comment: why you use  td+td?

Answer (score 0):

Give cellspacing some value

```css
td {border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td>1st</td>
    <td>2nd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be in a separated file, you can manage cellspacing with CSS.

Checkout this link : [CSS Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)

Comment: i try it doesn't work etheir the css is separate or not

Comment: that is not what I wanted to say. What you need is to change the border-spacing : 
`.mytable {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 25px 40px;
}`